# Hibernate Query Language Update Error

Tags: hql

```
Query query = session.createQuery("Update Contact set firstname = 'sdf' where firstname= 'Deepak'");
int result = query.executeUpate();
```

when executing the above query, I am getting the following error

```
    expecting DOT, found '=' near line 1, column 30 
[Update Contact set firstname = 'sdf' where firstname= 'Deepak']
```

Can someone please help me with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing the query in SQL, Not HQL.  A bulk update in HQL would look something like this:

```
String query = "update Contact c set c.firstname = :newName where c.name = :oldName";
int result = s.createQuery( query )
        .setString( "newName", "sdf")
        .setString( "oldName", "Deepak" )
        .executeUpdate();
```

However, unless there are lots of rows with firstname deepak, this is the wrong approach.  If you are just updating one object, it's better to a) do a query which returns this object, and b) update the object just by `myobject.firstname = "sdf";`